# Deploy two seperate iOS apps via PhoneGap with the same certificate/provisioning file

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate, provisioning-profile

We'd like to deploy two apps onto our iPad, using the same code base and configuration. The only difference being one points to our test environment, and the other to our production environment.

I'm using the build.phonegap.com service (this may or may not be relevant), and so far I've tried to change the Name and Id (i.e. com.company.app) in the config.xml file, but everything I deploy and download, the app overwrites itself. As mentioned above, we want two apps at the same time on the device, pointing to different environments.

I have a hunch that I may need to use a different certificate for each app (so that it is built with a different bundle id i.e. com.company.app)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to build each app with a different BundleID if you want them to show up as separate apps on the device. However, you can use the same certificate/profile as long as you set up the profile to contain both BundleIDs, or some wildcard that will match both BundleIDs.